# How can I show that the following Complex problem

Tags: complex-numbers

How can we show that $ z=-i/5 $ is contained in

$$ S= \{ z \in { \Bbb {C} } : \left| \frac { (z+1) ^ {z+1} }{ (z-1) ^ {z-1} }  \right| \lt {1}\} .$$

Answer (score 1):

You just have to plug the value $z=i/5$ into the expression of the condition, and see if the condition holds:

If $\left| \frac { (z+1) ^ {z+1} }{ (z-1) ^ {z-1} }  \right| \lt {1}$ then $z$ is in $S$,

if $\left| \frac { (z+1) ^ {z+1} }{ (z-1) ^ {z-1} }  \right| \geq {1}$ it is not in $S$.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please clarify the answer please?

Comment: What is not clear so far?